# Sharing Android code (Is there really no way to do this?)

Tags: android

I have a particular collection of code along with some XML files that I need to share with every application I will make.

At the moment I can't because as far as I am aware there is no way to do this.  This seems like a massive oversight by the development team.

If the code needs changing, I have to change it in every app that I create - and will create in the future.

Are there any ways to share code in android yet?

I am using Eclipse for development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject). The [TicTacToeMain](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/TicTacToeMain/index.html) sample project in the SDK shows how to reference your created library project.

Comment: Your answer is much better. +1

Comment: This looks interesting, I will check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can reference a third party JAR like you would any Java project.  Or are you talking about something else?

As for sharing XML files, I think you may have to just copy them to each project, but I'm not certain about that.

Comment: Sure, I know you can distribute jars.  I am more concerned about the rest - drawables, strings, ids, layouts etc.  If I change a simple xml id I then have to go through all my apps and change them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse particular `Activity` classes in applications other than the one they were installed with.  Is that sufficient?

To do that, you need to set `android:exported="true"` in the Activity's declaration in AndroidManifest.xml.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html has more details.